# In AngularJs, how do I identify a specific scope within a controller that is used multiple times on a page?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have an application that uses multiple tabs with a grid in each tab.  I have multiple pages using this same configuration.

I have a single controller that works for all grids.  I would like to reuse this controller throughtout my application.

My problem is that I am trying to lazy load the data for each tab until the tab is clicked.  What I can't figure out is how to tell the controller which scope belongs to which tab and ONLY get the data for that grid.  I know internally AngularJs does this because if I just load all the data for each tab at once I can click on my paginator, search, etc. for each tab and only that scope is updated.

I have ng-click setup for each tab and I can get my controller to fire when a tab is clicked.  However, the controller calls all instantiated scopes to load data for their respective grids.

My approach may not be the best but it seems silly to create seperate controllers that do exactly the same thing.

Note: Angular UI tabs with bootstrap is not an option.

My view

```
<div ng-app="TabsApp">
    <div tabs>
        <div class="tabs">
            <a ng-click="clickTab(0)" ng-class="{selected: selectedTab==0}">Localized Text From Server</a>
            <a ng-click="clickTab(1)" ng-class="{selected: selectedTab==1}">Localized Text From Server</a>
            <a ng-click="clickTab(2)" ng-class="{selected: selectedTab==2}">Localized Text From Server</a>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div ng-show="selectedTab==0" ng-init="init(@Model.UserId, 'useraddresses')" ng-controller="ListCtrl">@Html.Partial("_Grid0")</div>
            <div ng-show="selectedTab==1" ng-init="init(@Model.UserId, 'userphones')" ng-controller="ListCtrl">@Html.Partial("_Grid1")</div>
            <div ng-show="selectedTab==2" ng-init="init(@Model.UserId, 'usernotes')" ng-controller="ListCtrl">@Html.Partial("_Grid2")</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My app and factory url

```
var TabsApp = angular.module("TabsApp", ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

TabsApp.factory('Api', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/user/:userId/:ctrl', { userId: '@userId', ctrl: '@ctrl'});
});
```

My controller - child scope(s)

```
var ListCtrl = function ($scope, $location, Api){
    $scope.search = function () {
        Api.get({
            userId: $scope.userId,
            ctrl: $scope.ctrl,
            q: $scope.query
            //etc.
            },
                function(data){
                    $scope.items = data.items;
                    //other mapping
                });
    };

    $scope.init = function(userId, ctrl){
        $scope.userId = userId;
        $scope.ctrl = ctrl;
    };
    $scope.reset = function(){
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.search();
    };

    //kind of a hack but broadcasting was the only way I could figure out to listen for tab changes
    $scope.tabModelChange = { 'isChanged': false };
    $scope.$on('tabModelChange', function(event, args) {
        $scope.tabModelChange.isChanged = true;
        var activeTab = args.val[$scope.selectedTab];
        if (!activeTab.isLoaded) {
            $scope.reset();
        }
    }); 

    //filtering, sorting, pagination, etc.
};
```

My directive: Parent scope

```
TabsApp.directive('tabs', function () {
    return {
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.selectedTab = 0;
            $scope.tabModel = [];

            //I use localized text and any number of tabs on my views from the server so the client wont know how many tabs each view will have
            var tabs = angular.element($element.children()[1]).children();
            angular.forEach(tabs, function (value, key) {
                $scope.tabModel.push({'isLoaded' : false, 'isActive': false});
            });
            $scope.clickTab = function(tab) {
                $scope.selectedTab = tab;
                $scope.tabModel[$scope.selectedTab].isActive = true;
            };
            $scope.$watch('tabModel', function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    $scope.$broadcast('tabModelChange', { 'val': newVal });
                }
            }, true);
        }
    };
});
```

I suspect that when my controller receives a broadcast that the tab model has changed it calls $scope.reset with $scope being a parent scope which then traverses the child scopes looking for 'reset'.  Because there are 3 instances of ListCtrl, parent scope finds 3 child scopes with 'reset'. Hence, all the data gets loaded at once.

How can I get $scope.reset to match the tab that was clicked?  Thanks.

Comment: hard to follow full issue....creating a demo in plunker will help

Comment: Try using ng-init to pass a parameter to a function in the controller which sets the data source.

Comment: @DannyVarod that makes the most sense but how would I map that parameter to the specific scope.  A scope =1 may not correlate to the actual angular scope.

Comment: pass data to attribute of your `tabs` element. Then bind  it in scope within directive

Comment: @charlietfl, I may not understand your suggestion completely but I believe I am already doing that on my $scope.clickTab event.  Once the controller get's the change in the tabModel I call $scope.reset().  However, all child scopes get their data updated as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: what i'm suggesting is `<div tabs tabs-data="someScopeArray">`. Then tabs don't need to watch model changes...angular will do it for you . Inside directive add scope property to bind to array in attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With minimal change to your existing code, here's a plunker that does what you want, I think.

http://plnkr.co/edit/TVwWQehgWJay7ngA8g6B?p=preview

Basically I made a second directive called `tab` that accepts an argument which is a function to evaluate when that tab is switched to.

```
TabsApp.directive('tab', function () {
    return {
        require: '^tabs',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, tabsCtrl) {
            tabsCtrl.add({
                'isLoaded' : false, 
                'isActive': false, 
                'changed': function () { scope.$eval(attrs.tab); }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: The tab functionality is definitely better than what I had, but how do hook into my controller $scope.reset function to load my data?  Noob, if you haven't been able to tell already.

Comment: Uhh I'm not sure I follow.  Are you using chrome?  Did you open the plunker? F12 and you'll see as you click the links at the top the appropriate URL's are executed.  You do `tab="reset()"` to use this directive and then whatever you stick in the double quotes will get evaluated against the scope when that tab is changed to.

Comment: Sorry.  I went over it too fast. I have an embarrassment of riches to try out.  This looks really good.  I will try it.

Comment: Alright if this works, don't forget to upvote/accept and if it doesn't let me know!

Comment: Brilliant!  Works perfectly.  +1 for "With minimal change to your existing code".  Thanks Jared.  I like angular again.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we do (i'm a bit lazy and going to pull use our code), We load when tab is clicked.

Here's the tabs

```
    <ul class='nav nav-pills'>        
        <li ng-class="{ active : mode == 'incomplete'}"><a tabindex="-1" href="#/incomplete" ng-click='mode="incomplete"'>Incomplete orders</span></a></li>        
        <li ng-class="{ active : mode == 'completed'}"><a tabindex="-1" href="#/completed" ng-click='mode="completed"'>Completed orders</a></li>
    </ul>
```

We setup routes

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$env', function ($routeProvider, $env) {
     $routeProvider.when("/completed", {
        templateUrl: $env.urlRoot + "content/partials/orders/completed.htm",            controller: 'CompletedOrdersCtrl'
     });
    $routeProvider.when("/incomplete", {
        templateUrl: $env.urlRoot + "content/partials/orders/incomplete.htm",  controller: 'IncompleteOrdersCtrl'
     });
     $routeProvider.otherwise({
        templateUrl: $env.urlRoot + "content/partials/orders/incomplete.htm", controller: 'IncompleteOrdersCtrl'
     });
} ]);
```

We then have the two controllers IncompleteOrdersCtrl and CompleteOrdersCtrl that call the service to get the correct data. You could possibly consolidate into one controller with a parameter passed in the route config.

Hopefully this works for you

--dan

Comment: Having an aha moment.  I started with a route provider but couldn't get past the 'when' when using multiple tabs.  The 'href="#/incomplete"' solves that.  Great idea!  Thanks Dan.  I will try this out as well.